# Responsive navigation bar is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my responsive nav bar code in HTML and CSS. I don't know why it is not working but i used the same code before in my personal portfolio website. When i tried, the same in my new website it is not working. Please, help me where i am doing it wrong.

Thank You!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".menu-icon").on("click",function(){
          $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");

        });
});
```

```css
       /*--------------nav rules----------*/
   body{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    
     ul {
        background-color: red;
     opacity: 0.7;
     font-weight: bolder;
     overflow: hidden;
     color: white;
     padding: 0;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 0;
    }
    
    li {
        display: inline-block;
     padding: 20px;
    }
    
    li a{
     text-decoration: none;
     color: inherit;
    }
    
    li a:hover {
        background-color: #111;
    }
    
    .menu-icon{
     width: 100%;
     background-color: black;
     opacity: 0.7;
     text-align: right;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 15px 10px;
     cursor: pointer;
     color: #fff;
     display: none;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 580px){
     nav ul{
      max-height: 0px;
     }
     nav ul li{
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: left;
     }
      .menu-icon{
       display: block;
      }
    
      .showing{
       max-height: 20em;
    
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    <nav>
        <div class="menu-icon">
         <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
        
      <ul id="navlist">
       <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
       <li><a href="eminities.html">Eminities</a></li>
       <li><a href="#reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>
       <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      
    
     </nav>
```

Comment: Maybe some of your external resources aren't loading properly?  Seems to be working fine for me in this fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtwzd4kd/)

Comment: Yes, works fine for me too. Check your console by inspecting an element and see if you have any errors.

Comment: Same here.  I was able to get the menu to work properly.  I do see that you have two references to font-awesome css in the <head>.  I don't believe that has anything do with it, but it probably wouldn't hurt to remove it.

Comment: I tried all the possible ways, still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a problem with jquery script that you're loading

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In HTML, the scripts are placed in the same directory as your webpages, so there is no problem using the above statement. May be you don't have the file in the new website that you are creating.

Try using inspect element and see whether there is an error that says something like 'failed to laod script.' If that is so, try using

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"/>
```